# Is there a standard to represent databases as a XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I would like to work with XML for a small project, is there a standard to how we should represent an XML database? Everybody can represent a database using an XML file in many different schemas, I saw different examples on the internet on how to read/write an XML database but non are the same, so is there something I can rely on that many people would use? I doubt that there exists a library which can parse a XML database.

I tried searching on the internet about this problem, but didn't find any article that would help

Comment: It depends mainly on your definition of "database" and what you need from that database.

Comment: You can take a look at BaseX XML database: https://basex.org/